# Due to page reload, the video uploaded sing st.file_uploader() in streamlit is lost. How to retain it?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a streamlit app with sidebar, which consists of a radio button with 2 values: A & B. Both A & B uses st.file_uploadeer() to upload videos to the app.
However, when I switch between A & B, the uploaded videos get lost due to page reload. How can I retain the uploaded video unless the user specifically changes the uploaded file?
I think it can be done using session states or on_change() callback of the st.file_uploader() function, but I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

[Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2tpv.png)

```
import streamlit as st

val=st.sidebar.radio('Pick one!',['A','B'])

def upload_video(key):
    #Let's user upload a file from their local computer
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(
            'Choose a file', key=key)

    if uploaded_file is not None:
        # gets the uploaded video file in bytes
        bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
        file_details = {'Filename: ': uploaded_file.name,
                        'Filetype: ': uploaded_file.type,
                        'Filesize: ': uploaded_file.size}
        # st.write('FILE DETAILS: \n', file_details)
        st.write('\n\nUploaded video file')
        # displays the video file
        st.video(uploaded_file)

        # saves the uploaded video file
        with open(uploaded_file.name, "wb") as vid:
            vid.write(bytes_data)
        return uploaded_file.name
# if the user presses "A" in the radio button
if val=="A":
    upload_video("A")

# if the user presses "B" in the radio button
if val=='B':
    upload_video("B")
```

**I've added the code snippet**
Now when I press the B button in sidebar and then navigate back to A, the uploaded video will be cleared. How to solve this?
Also, this is my first stack overflow post, I apologize for any mistakes in asking the questions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code in addition to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like this :

```
import streamlit as st

val = st.sidebar.radio('Pick one!', ['A', 'B'])


def upload_video(key):
    st.write('key : ', key)
    if 'video_path' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['video_path'] = None
    # Let's user upload a file from their local computer

    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(
        'Choose a file', key=key)
    if st.session_state['video_path'] != None:
        agree = st.checkbox(
            'Previous file found! Do you want to use previous video file?')
        if agree:
            vid = open(st.session_state['video_path'], 'rb')
            video_bytes = vid.read()
            st.video(video_bytes)
            return st.session_state['video_path']

    if uploaded_file is not None:
        # gets the uploaded video file in bytes
        bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
        file_details = {'Filename: ': uploaded_file.name,
                        'Filetype: ': uploaded_file.type,
                        'Filesize: ': uploaded_file.size}
        # st.write('FILE DETAILS: \n', file_details)
        st.session_state['video_path'] = uploaded_file.name
        st.write(st.session_state['video_path'])
        st.write('\n\nUploaded video file')
        # displays the video file
        st.video(uploaded_file)

        # saves the uploaded video file
        with open(uploaded_file.name, "wb") as vid:
            vid.write(bytes_data)
        return uploaded_file.name


# if the user presses "A" in the radio button
if val == "A":
    upload_video("A")

# if the user presses "B" in the radio button
if val == 'B':
    upload_video("B")
```

Video file still remain present until you manually refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a few customizations that my code demanded!